# accessing s3 from lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda outside VPC which is accessing S3. I can access S3 from lambda when public access is on. But when I switch off the public access and create a bucket policy which allows only my lambda function to access S3 then I cant access the S3 anymore and I get a time-out error. I think there is something wrong in my policy. But I am not sure what. Here is my policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "LambdaAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/service-role/Lambda_accessingS3-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::uploads-from-lambda567",
                "arn:aws:s3:::uploads-from-lambda567/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Can somebody  please explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: lacking permissions in S3 never result in a timeout.

Answer (score 2):

A **time-out error** is an indication that you are not reaching the Amazon S3 API endpoints. It is *not* related to the Bucket Policy.

If you changed the AWS Lambda function to connect to a VPC, then it **no longer has access to the Internet**.

If at all possible, it is always better to *NOT* configure Lambda functions to use a VPC. When a VPC is *not* configured then the function has direct access to the Internet. However, if the Lambda function also requires access to resources in a VPC then you would either need to:

- Add a VPC Endpoint for S3 in the VPC, *or*
- Configure the AWS Lambda function to use private subnets and launch a NAT Gateway in a public subnet

If your particular goal is to simply to remove public access from the bucket but permit access to the Lambda function, and the Lambda function does not need to access any resources in the VPC, then simply remove the VPC configuration from the Lambda function and the Bucket Policy shown in your question should work correctly. Worst-case you will receive an `Access Denied` error, but never a time-out error.

Answer (score -1):

Since you switched off Public access for your s3 bucket, lambda can't access the bucket's Public Ip address to connect to it.

You can move the lambda function into VPC and create a VPC Gateway endpoint for your s3 bucket to enable the lambda function to access the bucket privately without going through the internet.

Comment: but i want to go through the internet

Comment: Then you need to make it publicly available

Comment: but when i put lambda inside vpc and use nate gateway to access S3 then i can access S3 even when public access is off and bucket policy allowing access only  from Nat gateway's ip address.

Comment: Isnt that what you want, to securely access your s3 bucket from lamdba without exposing it to the internet?

Comment: yes but without using nat gateway and vpc endpoints. i want to use bucket policies to provide access only to my lambda

Comment: You need to make the bucket public(else you would get timeout) since the lambda is not within the VPC and you don't intend to use the VPC endpoint. However anyone with this URL would be able to access the bucket, but you can restrict permission for "AWS users and roles" using permissions.

Comment: thats why i did: used lambda role in the policy but it is not working

Comment: You need to make the bucket public

Comment: "Since you switched off Public access for your s3 bucket, lambda can't access the bucket's Public Ip address to connect to it." that's not what public access does.  Public Access is an ACL/Policy thing not an IP thing.

Comment: "access only from Nat gateway's ip address" Fine, but simpler and just as secure is to use IAM policies to control bucket access.

Comment: "yes but without using nat gateway and vpc endpoints" does your lambda actually *need* to run in a VPC?  They don't have to be in a VPC, and can access the internet without any infrastructure if you don't put them in a VPC